# Cursor is not visible in EditText when no text is there

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText declared as below.

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Black"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
/>
```

But its not not displaying the cursor, when getting focus. When I starts typing, its showing the cursor from 1st index. I want the cursor to be displayed even in empty edittext.

I have already tried `setSelection(0)`but nothing happened. Please help me what should I do?

Comment: iam having the same problem could you pls help me!

Comment: Am I missing something here? The flagged duplicate question here is not the same at the OP. If you are here because the cursor simply isn't showing until you have at least 1 character, then check your edittext width. This will happen if it's `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Add some padding to make cursor visible.

Comment: @veritas1 Thank you very much!!! In my case extra padding changed nothing, instead I used `android:minWidth="5dp"` and it made the result. Thanks again!

Comment: If your `EditText` is `wrap_content`, then either set `android:minWidth` (in my case 5dp didn't work, nor 10dp, but I had to do 20dp) or you can also do `android:hint=" "` (with the space, if you don't want a hint)

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned above, here's the actual line

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

fyi - @null didn't show up as an autocomplete option

Comment: Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is available in API level 12 and higher . Any solution for this?

Comment: on some devices, like G4 it doesn't show even with that.. any suggestions?

Comment: I found that adding a hint made the the cursor display on an otherwise empty EditText